# Getting the last element of a heterogeneous list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define a function (`hLast`) that returns the last element of a heterogenous list:

```hs
type family HLastR xs where
  HLastR '[x] = x
  HLastR (x ': xs) = HLastR xs

class HLast xs where
  hLast :: HList xs -> HLastR xs

instance HLast '[x] where
  hLast (x `HCons` HNil) = x

instance (HLast xs, HLastR xs ~ HLastR (x ': xs)) => HLast (x ': xs) where
  hLast (x `HCons` xs) = hLast xs
```

With this code, GHC always complains that there are overlapping instances for `HLast`. I don't understand how the instances could ever overlap: An `HList` of more than one element only matches the second instance and singletons should only match the first instance since the second instance requires an `HLast` instance for the tail (`HNil` in the singleton case, for which there is no instance).

Adding an `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` directive to the first instance solves the problem, but this feels like an overly hacky solution for such a simple problem. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Constraints are not considered when checking overlap.  That would require the instance resolver to do backtracking:  E.g. let's try `HLast (x ': [])` instance, that requires `HLast '[]` which doesn't exist, so let's go back and try the other `HLast '[x]` instance.   It does not work this way, we just pick the best matching head without considering constraints and venture blindly forward.

Comment: I think `HLast '[x]` and `HLast (x ': y ': xs)` should work though.

Comment: I see, then I actually prefer the `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` solution. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I'm not quite enough of a type-level hacking expert to come up with an example off the top of my head, but I suspect `{-# OVERLAPPING #-}` will in *some* situation choose the latter instance when the list only has one element.  One where the typechecker has determined that the list is a cons, but has no information yet about the tail (which later ends up being `[]`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `HList` is defined as a GADT, you don't need a type class in the first place.

```hs
data HList xs where
  HCons :: x -> HList xs -> HList (x ': xs)
  HNil :: HList '[]

type family HLastR xs where
  HLastR '[x] = x
  HLastR (x ': xs) = HLastR xs

hlast :: HList xs -> HLastR xs
hlast (HCons x HNil) = x
hlast (HCons _ xs@(HCons _ _)) = hlast xs
```

Comment: That's more flexible, but it has rather different inlining behavior. There be trade-offs.